# How many USB's can I connect to a PC running Windows and what drive letters do they get assigned?

Tags: windows, usb

Consider the following scenario:

On my PC I have only one partition, with the drive letter C.

If I connect a USB hub or more, what happens / which drive letters get assigned to the USBs if they exceed the A to Z available list of drive letters?

If I connect for example 50 USB memory sticks - how will the drives get named after A to Z will get used, for the remaining number of USB memory sticks?

Comment: Windows does support assigning more then 26 drives a letter.  You have not really provided enough details about this configuration.  You can mount multiple drives to slightly different locations.  Please edit your question to describe the piratical problem you are experiencing.

Comment: "the piratical problem" - Ooh Arrrr me hearties!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Chrome spellcheck to the rescue.  Almost has efficient has the Rescue Rangers.